# net_version changes every time ganache starts

Tags: ganache, the-graph

I'm running ganache with the `--database.dbPath` option to store the state between starts. I'm also using a graph-node instance to index the events of the smart-contracts. This works fine the first time the graph-node is started but on subsequent starts it fails to launch the block ingestor with following errors:

```
ERRO the net version for chain mainnet has changed from 1661112863217 to 1661115401791 since the last time we ran, component: BlockStore
ERRO Not starting block ingestor (chain is defective), network_name: mainnet
```

ganache indeed changes the response for `net_version` after every start.

My question is: how can I get rid of the error in the graph-node? Either by ignoring the net version, setting the net version to the correct value before starting or faking the response from ganache.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option for that in the `ganache cli`: `--chain.networkId` documented [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#startup-options)